# Encoding issue using XZIP

Tags: c++, encoding

I wrote a c++ program that needs to zip files in it's work. For creating these zip files I used the XZip library. While developing this program ran on a Win7 machine and it works fine.
Now the program should be used on a WindowsXP machine. The issue I run into is:
If I let XZip create the zip archive "ü.zip" and add the file "ü.txt" to it on Win7 it is working as intended. On WindowsXP however I end up having the "ü.zip" file with "³.txt" as file in it.

The "³" => "ü" thing is of course an encoding issue between UTF8 and Ascii (ü = 252 in UTF8 and 252 = ³ in Ascii) BUT I can't really imagine how this could affect the creating of the internal zip structure in different ways depending on the OS.

//EDIT to clear it up:
the problem is that I run a test with XZip on Win7 and get the archive "ü.zip" containing the file with name "ü.txt".
When I run that test on an XP machine I get the archive "ü.zip" containing the file "³.txt".

//Edit2:
The thing that makes me wonder about that is, what exactly causes the zip to change between XP and Win7. The fact that it does change means that either a windows function behaves differently or XZip has specific behavior for different OS built in.
When having a quick look at XZip I can't see that it changes the encoding flag on the zip archives. The question of course only can be answered by people who did have a closer look into this exact problem before.

Comment: I didn't quite get what the problem was. If it's not the filename, then what's going wrong?

Comment: the problem is the name of the internal file. I updated my initial post.

Comment: The ZIP file format is quite old, older than unicode itself. Unicode support for ZIP has been added quite late. Windows has no problems with Unicode filenames, but you get into problems with older zip libraries. I assume you're using XZip on both XP and 7? Wat does Windows itself think about the archive content?

Comment: I use the exactly same program on xp and 7 and when creating a zip on xp both every zip-viewer (including the windows one) on every os says there is "³.txt" in the archive.

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule, if you want any sort of portability between locales, OS's (including different versions) and what have you, you should limit your filenames to the usual 26 letters, the 10 digits, and perhaps '_' and '-' (and I'm not even sure about the latter), and one '.', no more than three characters from the end.  Once you start using letters beyond the original ASCII character set, you're at the merci of the various programs which interpret the character set.

Also, 252 isn't anything in ASCII, since ASCII only uses character codes in the range 0...127.  And in UTF-8, 252 would be the first byte of a six byte character.  Something that doesn't exist in Unicode: in UTF-8, LATIN SMALL LETTER U WITH DIAERESIS would be the two byte sequence 0xC3, 0xBC.  256 **is** the encoding of LATIN SMALL LETTER U WITH DIAERESIS in ISO 8859-1, otherwise known as Latin-1; it's also the encoding in UTF-16 and UTF-32.

None of this, of course, should affect what is in the file.

Answer (score 0):

May be you are building your Win32 program (or the library) as ASCII (not as UNICODE). It may help if you build your Win32 applications with UNICODE configuration setting (you may change it in your Visual Studio project settings).

It is impossible to say what happened in your program without seeing your code. May be your library or the archive format is not UNICODE-aware, may be your program's code is not UNICODE-aware, may be you don't handle strings careful enough, or may be you just have to change your project setting to UNICODE. Also your "8-bit encoding for non-Unicode programs" Windows OS setting matters if you don't use UNICODE strings.

As for 252, UTF8 and ASCII read post by James Kanze. It is more or less safe to use ASCII file names with no ':', '?', '*', '/', '\' characters. Using non-ASCII characters may lead to encoding problems if you are not using UNICODE-based programs and file-systems.